# PDO 'fetchAll' return rows with an extra array

Tags: php, arrays, oop, pdo

I'm pulling some data from database with PDO and the data returns with an extra array that I can't understand where it comes from.

I have the option to use `call_user_func_array` to "exit" one array and I tried to but it slows my work.

I just prefer my code to work as I'm expecting and not start messing with it and make it "dirty". Other than that I couldn't find a solution.

This is my `select` method that I am using to pull the data:

```
public function select($whattoselect, $fromwhere, $condition){
      $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT {$whattoselect} FROM {$fromwhere} {$condition}");
      $stmt->execute();

      $this->row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      return $this;
}
```

This is how I am printing out the results (just for troubleshooting):

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($check->row());
echo '</pre>';
```

That is the output I am getting:

```
array(
 0 = array(
  key1 => value1, 
  key2 => value2
 )
)
```

That is the output I am trying to get:

```
array(
 key1 => value1, 
 key2 => value2
)
```

Comment: What? Why would you not expect fetchAll to return an array of rows? I mean it's in the name, "all". If you just want one row at a time, call `fetch` in a loop. Have a read of the docs for [fetchAll](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) and [fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).

Comment: Look about right, fetchAll return an array of all rows from your result from your query, your query only have one result so the result look like above. You have to use  `$results[0]` to get the first (and only in your case) row

Comment: @Jonnix It was so simple that i didn't even thought about it i am truly sorry for taking your time although your comment was very useful for me. Thanks.

Comment: If you're only wanting a single row, you can also add `LIMIT 1` to your query as well

Comment: @AfikHabaz Nothing to apologise for. Just be careful where you use it. Your function `select` looks very generic, so simply returning 1 row all the time might not really be what you want. The better option for you _might_ be to select the first item in the array that's returned later on when you need the row, but I don't know your code, so can't say for sure.

Comment: This is possible quite annoying and maybe helpful. I also want to return an array result but the result will not know key values in advance, so only want to loop through the result array and display the results, now I get 2 sets of results and find it difficult to only display one....

Comment: I ended up do an is_int($key) on the key as I loop through the value set to only get one set of data where the key is unknown..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetchAll` will return a two-dimensional array.

- The first dimension is each row.
- The second dimension is each field (key/value pair) within that row.

`$resultset[0]['fieldname']` will return the value of fieldname in the first row of the result set.

You're expecting `fetchAll` to return a single row whereas that's what `fetch` does.

So to keep it simple:

- If your result set will always only return one row, use `fetch`.
- If your result set could return multiple (or zero) rows, use `fetchAll` and then for each to iterate through each row.